# How to convert Salesforce Date Time to Unix format

Tags: apex

Please let me know how to convert salesforce datetime() to Unix format in apex.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DateTime method format(String s) and pass in a string using Java Simple Date Fomat.  Using [Java Simple Date Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you can get any format you would like.  You would use it like this.

```
DateTime myDT = system.now();
String myFormattedDT = myDT.format('mm/d/yyyy');
```

I would look into the Java Simple Date Format documentation and use that to get the desired output you are looking for.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format